# Архивирование с помощью SharpZipLib

Tags: winrar, c#

Здравствуйте! Для архивирования файлов использую библиотеку SharpZipLib 0.85.5.0. 
[Архивирование, разархивирование потоков, файлов и папок с использованием SharpZipLib .net & .net compact](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/fordesktopru/thread/5bd10b1d-5890-413a-8b37-f0ac07dbeefd).
Проблема заключается в том, что после создания архива, невозможно ни просмотреть, ни извлечь файлы из архива с помощью WinRar.

```
private static void CreateZip(ZipOutputStream zipOutStream, string name, string filePath)
        {
            ZipEntry fileZipEntry = new ZipEntry(name);
            zipOutStream.PutNextEntry(fileZipEntry);
            FileStream fileStram = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStram.Length];
            fileStram.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            zipOutStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            zipOutStream.CloseEntry();
        }

private void crtZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode tn = treeView1.SelectedNode;
            if (tn != null)
            {
                string FileZip = tn.Text + ".zip";
                ZipOutputStream ZipOut = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(FileZip));

                foreach (TreeNode node in tn.Nodes)
                {
                    CreateZip(ZipOut, node.Text, tn.Text + "/" + node.Text);
                }

                ZipOut.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Архив создан!");
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Выберите папку!");
        }
```

Другой вариант:

```
private static void CreateZip(ZipOutputStream zipOutStream, string name, string filePath)
        {
            ZipEntry fileZipEntry = new ZipEntry(name);
            zipOutStream.PutNextEntry(fileZipEntry);
            using (FileStream fileStram = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStram.Length];
                int src;
                do
                {
                    src = fileStram.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    zipOutStream.Write(buffer, 0, src);
                } while (src > 0);
            }
            zipOutStream.CloseEntry();
        }
```

Как видно, я выбираю узел в дереве, что соответствует существующей директории, затем создаю архив с таким же названием и туда архивируются все файлы из выбранной директории, которые также отображены в дереве.

Архив создается, файлы в нем есть, но вот извлечь или просмотреть их нельзя... WinRar пишет "Нет файлов для извлечения"...

В чем дело?..

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде точно есть ошибка: метод `int FileStream.Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)` [не обязан](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) читать именно `count` байтов. Необходимо в цикле читать из файлового потока и записывать буфер в `zipOutStream`.

Также стоит использовать конструкцию

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    // ...
}
```

при открытии потока, т.к. можно забыть его закрыть, как и происходит в данном случае.

Также попробуйте воспользоваться версией 0.86.0 библиотеки, там есть [некоторые исправления](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib_ReleaseHistory.ashx).

**UPD:** Сравнив код с примерами замечаю, что отсутствует

```
ZipOut.Finish();
```

перед закрытием потока.

Comment: Ммм.. На http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx 

Цикл построен так, что метод FileStream.Read() выполняется одни раз, так как numBytesToRead -= n; уменьшается на себя и становится равным нулю... Эт равносильно, что записать его без цикла...
Я смотрел и там и тут http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/net/113236/, пробовал по разному, но все равно эффект тот же... Библиотеку тоже поменял... WinRar ругается...

Comment: Это не верно, т.к. "Реализация может возвратить меньше байтов, чем было запрошено, даже если конец потока еще не достигнут."
После `stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` обязан быть прочитан по крайней мере один байт, однако не обязательно весь buffer.Length.

Comment: аааа finish стоит, прост в вопросе другая версия... а так я это тоже заметил и исправил, но все равно так же..